How to combine two pages with timer animation in Flutter?
I'm building a Pomodoro app in Flutter, and I want to combine two separate pages into one. The goal is to have the timer animation take up the entire screen from the bottom of the app bar to the bottom of the screen. Currently, I have the timer animation and the tab bar on separate pages.
The issue I'm facing is that I want the timer animation height to start from the bottom of the app bar and align the timer with the animation. In the future, when the timer is over, I want to automatically navigate to another page. I've included the relevant code snippets below.
Code:
startpomodoro.dart
    class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
      const StartPomodoro({Key? key,}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState();
    }
    
    class _StartPomodoroState extends State<StartPomodoro>
        with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

          @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
        return Scaffold(
          body: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
             // ... (code omitted for brevity)
            },
            child: AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: controller,
                builder: (context, child) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  AnimatedBuilder(
                                      builder: (context, child) {
                                        return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                              onPressed:() {
                                               // ... (code omitted for brevity)
                                              },
                                            ],
                                        );
                                    },
                                ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                      }


Homepagetimer.dart

    class HomePageTimerUI extends StatefulWidget  {
    
      const HomePageTimerUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<HomePageTimerUI> createState() => _HomePageTimerUIState();
    }
    
    class _HomePageTimerUIState extends State<HomePageTimerUI>  
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
    
      @override
      Widget build (BuildContext context) {
         return DefaultTabController(
                    // ... (code omitted for brevity)
                        child: Scaffold(
                          appBar: AppBar(
                            bottom: PreferredSize(
                              child: Container(
                               //code
                                child: SafeArea(
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      TabBar(
                                          tabs: [
                        // ... (code omitted for brevity)
                                        ],
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                          ),
                          body: TabBarView(
                // ... (code omitted for brevity)
                          ),
                          bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                            child: GNav(
                                gap: 8,
                                onTabChange: (index) {
                                  print(index);
                                },
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                                tabs: [
                 // ... (code omitted for brevity)
                                ],
                              ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                }



Please let me know if you have suggestions on how to achieve this design in a single page.

What went wrong while you've tried to merge it?

Hello, I just copy and paste the scaffold from startpomodoro.dart
inside Homepagetimer.dart but don't work

you can include the error that you’ve found, also try including minimal-reproducible-example
